# Best practice translate long texts with Java Spring i18n

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I use Java Spring i18n for translate my web page. I want to know what is best practice to translate long texts.

Example:
I have properties file usermsg_en.properties:

```
short_text = short line
long_text = post about something with lot of text lines...
```

and jsp file:

```
....
<div id="content"><spring:message code="long_text"/></div>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short texts or long texts, it doesn't really matter. When it comes to internationalization the really tricky thing is that translations of strings will be different lengths in different languages and this will often not sit well with your UI.

You really need to test your UI in every language you plan to offer it in to find where a string in a different language might break your layout.

Also a lot of assumptions that your software makes about dates/times/word orders etc can be completely off in other languages/locales.

There is a great article about internationalization [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/12-commandments-software-localization/)

We do a lot of internationalization stuff at my work from that list my top things would be:

- don't concatenate strings
- don't hardcode date/time/currency values
- give strings room to grow and shrink
- NEVER, never trust the browser to know the locale (underline 'never'
  and make a study)

Also if you aren't already you definitely want to be storing all strings in .properties files

Answer (score 2):

Everything that James Scott Tayler wrote is right: please follow his advice. Still, there are two more things about translating long strings that you may want to consider:

1. Avoid hard coded line breaks in your source language strings. Unless the translators have access to a live system where they can see where they need to place line breaks in the target language they simply won't know where the target language lines need to be wrapped. In theory this should not be a big issue for web sites, but I have seen way too many occurrences of `\n` in strings for web sites to not mention this.
2. Professional translators work in translation environments with [translation memories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory). Translation memories are databases that store previous translations, and whenever a translator encounters a new string that needs to be translated that string and the previous translation will be looked up in the translation memory. The typical storage unit for software UI texts is a single string, for documentation it is a sentence or a paragraph. When a translator opens a properties file for translation the translation memory will usually search for a single existing translation for your long text (since it comes from a properties file). If the long text had been processed sentence by sentence the translator may have gotten more matches, which means that the translation can be done faster and cheaper.

Of course the second issue does no longer apply after the first round of translation for your long texts. And it also does not apply if you do not have to pay for your translations. :-)

Comment: Yes, line breaks are another thing to watch out for! Same with you must watch out for business logic splitting strings by spaces because Asian languages often do not contain spaces, so that method won't work.